# Creating a named range using a macro or VBA where the name is within the worksheet located every 30 rows

Tags: excel, vba

```
source033   target033
3 4 5 6

1.0         3.4        5.3 
2.0         4.4        8.1 
3.0         5.4        11.0 
4.0         6.4        13.8 
5.0         7.4        16.7
```

I have a macro that every 30 rows creates this sequence of cells, incrementing the number that follows "source" and "target" by one for each 30 cells.

I'd like to add to that macro (listed below) the ability to name the range whose numbers in this example are 3,4,5,6 (this array is always the same location and size) as "Source033" (without the quotes) and the 5x3 array to the right (again, always the same size and location) as "Target033" (without the quotes).

When the macro is run again, the same structure appears, but the number associated with the words "source" and "target" will be again incremented by 1. Here is the macro that just recreates the structure every 30 rows, but leaves the naming of the ranges to the user -- still a pretty tedious task for hundreds of these iterations:

```
Sub build_selling_proceeds_sort()
 '
build_selling_proceeds_sort Macro
 '
Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+b

ActiveCell.Range("A1:AA24").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(30, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 2).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
ActiveCell.Range("A1:J1").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a general rule of thumb, you should avoid using `.Select` and `Selection` whenever possible. So you could clean up your existing code to look like this.

```
'This range seems large for what you're trying to do, but it's what you had
ActiveCell.Range("A1:AA24").Copy ActiveCell.Offset(30)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
```

I'm not exactly sure where the ranges you want to name "Source033" & "Target033" would be at. So I'll just do something generic

```
Dim sourceRange as Range, targetRange as Range
Set sourceRange = Range("A2")
Set targetRange = Range("A4:C8")
'I assume you've defined some incrementer x as 
'the number of times you've looped this statement
thisWorkbook.Names.Add "Source" + CStr(x), sourceRange
thisWorkbook.Names.Add "Target" + CStr(x), targetRange
```